# dynamically adding the select box when filling the other select box

Tags: javascript, html

hi i'm working on a form where it contains an input text box to fill the hobbies in that, here what i want is, whenever i'm entering the value in that input box i need to add another empty text box dynamically where i can add another value in that in the same way if they are entering any value into this new empty box another empty text box should add at the bottom of this. Using javascript & php how can i achieve that?
my code for that select box is

```
<div class="ma_form"><label style="width:32%;text-align: left;">hobbies:</label>
        <div class="ma_edit"><input type="text" name="c2hobby" id="c2hobby" value="" placeholder="Please enter a hobby" class="snappy aad" /></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's what you wanted, but...

Create your select box like this:

```
<select id="hobbies" style="display: none;"></select>
```

Then add the following JavaScript to the head of your document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("c2hobby").onkeyup = function(){
            document.getElementById("hobbies").style.display = (this.value.length > 0) ? "block" : "none";
        };
    };
</script>
```